# How to scrape the href attribute from an anchor tag using jQuery.ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape the href attribute from an anchor tag using jQuery.ajax, but I only get the URLs which are rendered in the HTML rather than all of them, because there is a Slider, e.g. 25/145. I want to get all the URLs.

How can I do this?

```js
var result = [];
var index = 0;
jQuery.ajax({
  async: false,
  type: 'POST',
  url: "https://www.usajobs.gov/Search/Results?a=TD03&p=1",
  headers: {
    'contentType': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
  },
  crossDomain: true,
  success: function(response) {
    var urls = $("#usajobs-search-results").find('a').each(function() {
      let url = $(this).attr('href');
      console.log(`https://www.usajobs.gov/${url}`);
    });
    for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
      result[index] = urls[i].href;
      index++;
    }
  },
});
```

Comment: Seems you will need to change X `https://www.usajobs.gov/Search/Results?a=TD03&p=X`  from 1 until 404

Comment: Hi , Thanks for Your Help , Now I got it working But can you please guide me a way to get the Slider last number e-g 1-6 or 1-10 so that I can Dynamically get all the Links if the Number Changes .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st do you have permission to scrape?

If so

Seems you need to change the X in

```
https://www.usajobs.gov/Search/Results?a=TD03&p=X
```

in the success

from 1 until 404

and use a setTimeout to call again to not hammer them
Also

```
 var urls = $("#usajobs-search-results a').map(function() {
   return this.href; }).get()
 })
```

Comment: Can you please Explain this to me a bit

Comment: How are you even able to do this? The payload is  JSON POST - are you using some kind of jQuery plugin to selenium?

Comment: Hello Sir, So I am able to Scrape Data somehow  but there is a problem i thought that the Code is Scraping all the Jobs Link form site which has a Slider and Shows total 25 pages , it was getting the total number of jobs as result , means its getting the result as total number of jobs Url but its Repeating the same 25 , its not moving to the next slider